# Exact Definition of a Function Question

Tags: functions

Let $f$ be a function from the null set to the null set.

I am curious as to why $f$ would be a function in this case, because doesn't there have to exist exactly one element in the null set for the codomain? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a unique element to match with each element of the domain, but there aren't any of those. It is the same phenomenon behind the fact that $(\forall x \in \emptyset) P(x)$ is true for any predicate $P$.

Comment: So in that example, why is it true for all of x that P(x) is true? Doesn't there have to be a vacuous implication somewhere in there? Please, can you explain more?

Comment: @W.G. It is not said that it is true for all $x$, but that it is true for all $x\in\varnothing$. This because in the set $\varnothing$ we simply cannot find an element for which it is *not* true. Even more strongly: we cannot even find an element whatsoever in $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given two sets $D$ and $C$, a relation between $D$ and $C$ is a triple $R=(D,C,G)$ where $G \subseteq D \times C$. The set $D$ is called the domain of $R$, $C$ is the codomain of $R$ and $G$ it's graph. If $(x,y) \in G$ you denote $xRy$.

A function $f: D \to C$ is a relation $f=(D,C,G)$ such that *for each* $x \in D$ exists one *unique* $y \in C$ such that $xfy$.

So in your case, you just have the triple $g=(\varnothing,\varnothing,\varnothing)$. This relation $g$ vacuously satisfies the function condition.

Comment: How does there exist exactly one unique y element of C then? I am still unsure what you mean by vacuous in this context and how it relates to there existing one unique y element of C.

Comment: if you have a proposition about elements of a set, if the set is empty, the proposition is always true, because there is no element of the empty set to make that proposition false

Answer (score 2):

$f=(A,B,E)$ is a **function** from a set $A$ to a set $B$ if, and only if, $E\subset A\times B$, and for all element $a\in A$ there exists a unique $b=f(a)\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in E$.

In your case, have $(\emptyset,\emptyset,\emptyset\times\emptyset)=(\emptyset,\emptyset,\emptyset)$ which satisfies the require conditions, because

$$\forall x\in \emptyset P(x)$$

is always true (since there is no counter-example obviously).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a function on the empty set? If so here is good wiki article which should answer your question: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function

Comment: I have read this article already, but thank you though.